# How to show UIView only when i received all data from server

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, nsurlconnection

I am getting data from server in my application. Currently I making this using NSUrlConnection and getting data in `connectionDidFinishLoading`. Mean while i am showing an alertView to user. but that time my view is not updated with data.

I can only show while whole response is came form server and refreshing the view later.

Can i restrict view to shown up only when whole response is acquired or can i make the that dark effect of uialertview  more dark which make containing view disable???

**EDIT:**

From all answers i would like to know that can i make gray effect of UIAlertView more dark or may i change it with other color ? or can someone explain me how its shown up ??

Comment: Do not present/push the controller until data is downloaded. Once download completes, create controller, pass data and then present/push it. Until then show activity indicator to the user. Showing alert/blocking the UI is not a good experience, IMO.

Comment: It's too abstract question. Give us some more details so we can answer it properly.
I think you can add overlapping view with black background color with opacity to your 'main' view when data starts loading, and after it finishes, remove overlapping view from superview

Comment: Remember that `UIViewControllers` are Controllers of View. The data loading should not be in UIViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)In viewDidLoad method you can add another temporary view with dark gray background color.

2)Add activity indicator in this temporary view & start that indicator and set user interaction disable for self view.

3)In connectionDidFinishLoading stop the indicator & remove temporary view and enable user interaction of self view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a overlay of darker color and an `UIActivityIndicator`, make the userInteraction disabled for that period for time