# how to load data to tableviewcontroller via web webservice?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, web-services, ios6

I have a `UITableViewCotroller` which will get its data from `NSArray`(RestaurantsArray),
this restaurant array is being field by using an object that call the web service an consume the returned `JSON` .
here is where i am trying to fill the array in the `UITableViewCotroller`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RestaurantsList* tempObject=[[RestaurantsList alloc]init];

    RestaurantsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    RestaurantsArray=[tempObject loadTheRestaurantList];  

 }
```

but the problem is that the request operation wouldn't fire until the tableviewcontroller end loading, so the `RestaurantsArray` remain null.

what I want is to call the web service , end the consuming operation then fill the array which will be the data source to the tableview

Comment: [tableview reloaddata]; relload table after getting the data from webservice

Comment: I tried this but the operation is being repeated as I am loading the view for the first time
by the way is there a compability to overwrite the "reload table" after I make sure that the array had been filled

Comment: I guess it is clear that i am using tableviewcotroller not a tableview

Comment: first time view load then in viewdidload method set tableview delgate as nil after getting response from websrvice set tableview delegate self and reload tableview got it ?

Comment: @Rushabh I don't think I understand your idea clearly, would you please explain more

Comment: check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512565/how-to-show-uiview-only-when-i-received-all-data-from-server

Answer (score 0):

What is loadTheRestaurantList method?
If you are using NSURLConnection to load data, there are a NSURLConnectionDelegate, that has the method

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

This method are called after your request is complete and loading are finished. In this method you can post notification by NSNotificationCenter and listen it in your UITableViewCotroller.